# return value from angularfire database list subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to sum the 'amount' value of each transaction in my 'expenses' list.

Here is my database:

[image]

The log within the subscribe works and totals 1700 but i can't get the value of 'this.expenseListTotal' out of the function to display it in another component. How do I return the 'this.expenseListTotal' value so I can use it in another component?

```
getExpenseListTotals(budgetId: string) {    
 this.afd.list('users/' + this.cUser.uid + '/budgets/' + budgetId + '/expenses').subscribe(_data => {       
   this.expenseListTotal = _data.reduce((sum, item) =>sum+item.amount,0);
  console.log("expennse list total = ",this.expenseListTotal, typeof this.expenseListTotal);
 });
}
```

Comment: What are you getting in console? any error or nothing??

Comment: it was logging the '1700' value which is the sum of the two transactions

Comment: Then just add `return this.expenseListTotal;` after console.log();

Comment: I tried. That was not working. I figured out a solution below. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in service:

```
getExpenseListTotals(budgetId: string) {

return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.total = this.afd.list('users/' + this.cUser.uid + '/budgets/' + budgetId + '/expenses').subscribe((_data) => {


    this.expenseListTotal =  _data.reduce((sum, item) =>sum+item.amount,0);
    resolve(this.expenseListTotal);


  });

  })
}
```

In component:

```
this.total = this.budgetService.getExpenseListTotals(this.budgetId);
this.total.then(function(value){
 console.log(value)
});
```